# Cannot find module 'node-sass'

Tags: npm-install, node-sass

use command

`npm install`

but the console still tell me:
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'.
and node-sass is in node_module

[image: screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Enjoy!